# On picard group of an irreducible curve inside a smooth hypersurface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, surfaces, curves, line-bundles

Let, $S$ be a smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ and let $C$ be a reducible curve inside $S$ and $C =C_1 \cup C_2 \cup ...\cup C_n$, be its decomposition in terms of irreducible components.

At this point my question is :Does there exist any relation in terms of short exact sequence relating $Pic (C_i),Pic(C)$ and $Pic(S)$?

Since $C_i$'s are irreducible curve,they can be thought of as effective divisor and therefore gives rise to line bundle on $S$,but that does not give me any precise relation.

Can somebody give me a reference discussing about it?

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: If $C$ were irreducible, what short exact sequence are we talking about, which will give information about the Picard group of $C$?

Comment: @Mohan,I am not quite sure whether I have understood your question or not.But I am looking for some short exact sequence similar to proposition $6.5(C)$ of chapter $2.6$ of Hartshorne

Comment: @Mohan,Is it true that if $Pic(S) \cong \mathbb Z$ then $n$ has to be $1$?

Comment: I clearly do not understand. Projective plane has plenty of reducible curves.

Comment: @Mohan,sorry I meant $S$  a hypersurface (I mean not a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$,i.e $S$ is not $\mathbb{P}^{2}$).I will edit that in my question

Comment: Any surface has many curves and so many reducible curves.

Comment: @Mohan,In that case under what conditions we can say that the curve is irreducible?Specifically if we assume $S$ is a very general surface, then any curve in $S$ is a complete intersection. Then under which condition it becomes irreducible e.g when $S \cap Z$ for some other hypersurface $Z$ is irreducible?

Comment: Whether $S$ is general or not, if $Z$ is general, then Bertini tells you $S\cap Z$ is irreducible. Other than that, what kind of conditions are you looking for?